# How do I get the "php artisan cache: clear" command to work?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-artisan

I'm using a Mac. Can not execute the command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

I get in return:

```
Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the proper permissions.
```

This is for Laravel. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Previously, this operation has always worked. Now I have created a new project as usual. And the first time I received this error.

Comment: execute pront with super admin and try

Comment: Is your `storage/framework/cache` folder set with the correct permissions? This started changing for me recently too when I had to run `composer` commands (such as `composer create-project laravel/laravel`) as `root` vs current user.

Comment: storage/framework/cache this folder is empty. Is it not normal?

Comment: run yout cdm pront inside folder with super admin and try you have all permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be one of several things(need more information to narrow it down):

1. **No cache files/records exist.**(Updated to reflect your latest comments)
2. If you are running a webserver (apache or ngix) as a different user, then you won't have permissions to the files as yourself.
3. If you are using a cache driver other than file, like redis or database, make sure the credentials provided are correct.
4. There could be a bug in the version of Laravel you are using; this would be unlikely.

Expansion on points 1 and 2:

1. This is normal behavior. If you have opened pages expecting them to be cached and they are not, split the page and utilize `@include` directives splitting out the dynamic and static elements of the page into separate blade files.
2. I like to add my user to the same group as the web server's group(*www*).  Then change the group for all of the files to *www*, with group read permissions, and write permissions only on the `bootstrap/cache` and `storage` directories.

Comment: @GeorgeHanson Any failure to delete files in 5.7 results in the message:
   $successful = $this->cache()->flush();
        $this->flushFacades();
        if (! $successful) {
            return $this->error('Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the 
   appropriate permissions.');
This is not a bug, just a change in the message. It used to ignore empty directories.

Answer (score 3):

create storage/framework/cache/data directory manually.

Comment: This will work if the directory doesn't exists. If it does then it is a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might possibly be a bug with the latest version of Laravel, however unlikely it may seem. I started a new project today and installed a fresh copy of Laravel 5.7 and it seems to cause the error above. However, if I use 5.6 then the error does not appear.